# node javascript file upload doesn't work on remote server

Tags: node.js, file-upload, apollo-server

On my local dev machine accessing localhost the following code works beautifully even with network settings changed to "Slow 3G." However, when running on my VPS, it fails to process the file on the server. Here are two different codes blocks I tried (again, both work without issue on local dev machine accessing localhost)

```js
  profilePicUpload: async (parent, args) => {
     const file = await args.file;
     const fileName = `user-${nanoid(3)}.jpg`;
     const tmpFilePath = path.join(__dirname, `../../tmp/${fileName}`);

     file
        .createReadStream()
        .pipe(createWriteStream(tmpFilePath))
        .on('finish', () => {
          jimp
            .read(`tmp/${fileName}`)
            .then(image => {
              image.cover(300, 300).quality(60);
              image.writeAsync(`static/uploads/users/${fileName}`, jimp.AUTO);
            })
            .catch(error => {
              throw new Error(error);
            });
        });
}
```

It seems like this code block doesn't wait long enough for the file upload to finish since if I check the storage location on the VPS, I see this:

[image]

I also tried the following with no luck:

```js
profilePicUpload: async (parent, args) => {
      const { createReadStream } = await args.file;
      let data = '';

      const fileStream = await createReadStream();

      fileStream.setEncoding('binary');

// UPDATE: 11-2
      let i = 0; 
      fileStream.on('data', chunk => {
        console.log(i);
        i++;
        data += chunk;
      });

      fileStream.on('error', err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
// END UPDATE


      fileStream.on('end', () => {
        const file = Buffer.from(data, 'binary');
        jimp
          .read(file)
          .then(image => {
            image.cover(300, 300).quality(60);
            image.writeAsync(`static/uploads/users/${fileName}`, jimp.AUTO);
          })
          .catch(error => {
            throw new Error(error);
          });
      });
}
```

With this code, I don't even get a partial file.

`jimp` is a JS library for image manipulation.

If anyone has any hints to get this working properly, I'd appreciate it very much. Please let me know if I'm missing some info.

Comment: What happens if you remove the `jimp` code? Does it store the entire file on the VPS or does it fail to do so too (using the first code)?

Comment: Also, add a listener to the stream's `error` event, so you can further debug it.

Comment: Thanks, @Skaparate. If I put a ```console.log('here')``` right before ```jimp```, it never gets triggered on the VPS but it does on local PC. I did this ```fileStream.on('error', err => {  console.log(err);   });``` below the ```fileStream.on('data'...``` and it didn't do anything. Am not sure if I'm using it right.

Comment: I assume you used the second code, right? Can you share the code? Which VPS are you using? By the way, if it's the second code, your `on('error'...` should display any errors.

Comment: @Skaparate I updated my code to reflect the troubleshooting changes I made. (sorry, I was caught up with other things for the last few days.) I'm running Ubuntu on my VPS. To test this, I setup a VirtualBox running the same configuration of Ubuntu on my LAN and it's having the same problem. On my localhost, ```i``` goes up to 30-33, whereas on the VPS and VM, it only goes up to 3-4. Seems like "on data" is timing out or quitting before it receives all the chunks. And as I mentioned before, no error messages "on error".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure out a solution by referring to this article: https://nodesource.com/blog/understanding-streams-in-nodejs/

Here is my final, working code:

```js
const { createWriteStream, unlink } = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const { once } = require('events');
const { promisify } = require('util');
const stream = require('stream');
const jimp = require('jimp');

profilePicUpload: async (parent, args) => {
      // have to wait while file is uploaded
      const { createReadStream } = await args.file;

      const fileStream = createReadStream();
      const fileName = `user-${args.uid}-${nanoid(3)}.jpg`;
      const tmpFilePath = path.join(__dirname, `../../tmp/${fileName}`);
      const tmpFileStream = createWriteStream(tmpFilePath, {
        encoding: 'binary'
      });

      const finished = promisify(stream.finished);

      fileStream.setEncoding('binary');

      // apparently async iterators is the way to go
      for await (const chunk of fileStream) {
        if (!tmpFileStream.write(chunk)) {
          await once(tmpFileStream, 'drain');
        }
      }

      tmpFileStream.end(() => {
        jimp
          .read(`tmp/${fileName}`)
          .then(image => {
            image.cover(300, 300).quality(60);
            image.writeAsync(`static/uploads/users/${fileName}`, jimp.AUTO);
          })
          .then(() => {
            unlink(tmpFilePath, error => {
              console.log(error);
            });
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
          });
      });

      await finished(tmpFileStream);
}
```